# distance and bearing between two geopoints in android

Tags: android, geolocation, distance, geopoints, bearing

i am trying to calculate the distance and bearing between two geopoints. This is a code that i have found on the internet but it returns different values.

```
double currentLat = 51.43376;
    double currentLng = -2.86221;

    double destLat = 51.43503; 
    double destLng = -2.86869;

    final float[] results= new float[3];
    Location.distanceBetween(currentLat, currentLng, destLat, destLng, results);
    System.out.println("GPS" + "results[0]: " + results[0]);
    System.out.println("GPS" + "results[1]: " + results[1]);
    System.out.println("GPS" + "results[2]: " + results[2]);


    Location here = new Location("Current");
    here.setLatitude(currentLat);
    here.setLatitude(currentLng);

    Location dest = new Location("Destination2");
    dest.setLatitude(destLat);
    dest.setLongitude(destLng);


    System.out.println("GPS" + "Bearing to dest: " + here.bearingTo(dest));
    System.out.println("GPS" + "Distance to dest: " + here.distanceTo(dest));
```

the logcat:

```
04-13 17:46:13.056: I/System.out(1349): GPSresults[0]: 472.2533
04-13 17:46:13.056: I/System.out(1349): GPSresults[1]: -72.5882
04-13 17:46:13.066: I/System.out(1349): GPSresults[2]: -72.59327
04-13 17:46:13.066: I/System.out(1349): GPSBearing to dest: -2.2131138
04-13 17:46:13.066: I/System.out(1349): GPSDistance to dest: 6023135.0
```

so can any one help me with these methods and tell me which one is the correct one to use.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code:

```
Location here = new Location("Current");
here.setLatitude(currentLat);
here.setLatitude(currentLng);
```

you set latitude twice. Corrected, it gives absolutely right result.

Comment: OH, i really feel embarrassed with this silly mistake. Thank you for your help.